# run code after transaction commit in Django

Tags: django, transactions, signals, commit

Is there any way to run some code after transaction commit in Django?

I need to send some messages to a rabbitmq server for offline processing, but the message gets to the consumer before the Django transaction is commited.

My message is sent in the post_save signal of the model. What I'm looking for is a similar mechanism, using signals or something else, that would execute code after the commit (and do nothing if the transaction fails).

I haven't found any generic way of doing it in Django. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I had a simmilar problem. On post_save, Publisher (process 1) saves task state and publishes the message. Consumer (process 2) receives the message and updates task state, which is not in the db yet. What worked was putting consumer to sleep for a second or two, after receiving the message. Feels dirty anyway.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[django-transaction-hooks](https://github.com/carljm/django-transaction-hooks) solves this problem for Django < 1.9, and the functionality is [built into Django 1.9+](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.on_commit):

```py
from django.db import transaction

def do_something():
    pass  # send a mail, invalidate a cache, fire off a Celery task, etc.

transaction.on_commit(do_something)
```

Comment: I have to work on some other parts of my app before, but I will follow this path. When it's ready, I'm going to drop an e-mail to django-developers and add a bug report with the patch.

Comment: If `django-transaction-hooks` requires too high a Django version, you can use `django-db-signals`.

Answer (score 15):

Hope this may help someone using Django 1.9 or later. Since 1.9 [on_commit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.on_commit) is available.

So basically you would be doing it like this:

```
from django.db import transaction

transaction.on_commit(
    lambda: send_msg_to_rabbitmqp(param1, param2, ...)
)
```

If you wish to keep `post_save`, you can still use `on_commit`:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    transaction.on_commit(
        lambda: send_msg_to_rabbitmqp(instance.id)
    )
```

Comment: Where should I put this code If I want the hooks to be executed every time on every transaction?

Comment: @styrofoamfly In the `save()` method of the model is where I put it. You can also register a `post_save` signal that calls `transaction.on_commit` and I think it get registered early enough to be called for that save transaction.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why we need the `lambda` syntax in order to pass parameters to the `on_commit` callable? Can `functools.partial` accomplish this in order to make it more obvious that we're calling a function with a full-definition elsewhere as opposed to a true, in-line lambda?

Comment: lambda is needed solely to turn `send_msg_to_rabbitmqp(instance.id)` into callable

Answer (score 5):

I have implemented transaction signals (`post_commit` and `post_rollback`) by monkey patching django:
http://gist.github.com/247844

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to subclass the transaction middleware so that it sends a custom signal on commit. Your code could listen for that signal, rather than post_save.

Comment: Thanks, I think that I will go with some middleware (I will probably add another middleware and not subclass the transaction middleware).

I have a concern about signals though. Are they thread safe? If another thread throws a signal, may the current thread catch it?

Comment: I still have an issue with middlewares : if the application is running from a management command, it won't execute my callbacks.

Comment: I don't think your thread question really makes sense. Signals don't do anything special with regard to threads. A signal sent in one thread will call receivers in that same thread only.  Built-in signal objects are module-global, however, so a signal handler registered for post_save in one thread is registered in all threads. (I think it might be possible to have signal objects in your own code that are not global, haven't looked at it carefully).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [django-celery-transactions](https://github.com/chrisdoble/django-celery-transactions) for a solution to this.

I've recently finished splitting-out and refactoring the underlying signals code code into a stand-alone app [django-db-signals](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-db-signals).