# Is there way to make costum signal when Manytomany relations created? Django!

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

Is there way to make custom signal when ManyToMany relations created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more details about what you are trying to accomplish I'd suggest that you take a look at this [previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958540/django-manytomany-signals). If this is not what you are looking for then posting more details (including code) about what you want to do will help.