# django manytomanyfield .add() method

Tags: python, django, overriding, manytomanyfield

Suppose i have :

```
class Album(models.Model):
    photos = models.ManyToManyField('myapp.Photo')
    photo_count = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

class Photo(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'blahblah')
```

What is want is, everytime i call .add() method, increment the `photo_count` on `Album` class, so i'm thinking to override .add() method. The problem is, i can't import the `.add()`'s class since it is inside a method, so it is like `def->class->def`. So is there anyway to override `.add()` ? Or there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You [can use django's signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/) and write a signal handler that will increment the counter using the `m2m_changed` signal:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest option is to skip signals, drop the photo_count field entirely and call [album].photos.count() anywhere you would have used [album].photo_count.

You could also define a property on Album as follows:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    photos = models.ManyToManyField('myapp.Photo')

    @property
    def photo_count(self):
        return self.photos.count()

class Photo(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'blahblah')
```

The downside of both options is they makes it harder to search / sort based on the number of photos. They also don't store the count in the database. (That might be import if you have some non-Django application which is interacting with the same DB.) If you think you'll want to do those sorts of searches via Django, look into [Django annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate).

This is simpler than dealing with signals, but probably still overkill.