# Order Django queryset by two concatenated M2M fields

Tags: python, django, orm, m2m

I have the following Django models (greatly simplified here):

```
class Author:
    name = models.TextField()

class Editor:
    name = model.TextField()

class Publication:
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    editors = models.ManyToManyField(Editor)
```

A publication can have *either* authors *or* editors, but not both. I would like to order a the list of publications by the unification of authors and editors, alphabetically sorted. In other words, I would like to order by a virtual field, let's call it `creators` which is the concatenation of authors and editors.

The query:

```
Publication.objects.all().order_by('authors__name', 'editors__name')
```

... will clump together the publications that have NO authors, and within that group sort according to editors, which is NOT what I want. Effectively, it should use whatever of authors or editors is available for a publication and sort by that.

This ordering has to happen at the database level, the result sets can be huge.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is creating a method called `creators`:

```
class Publication:
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    editors = models.ManyToManyField(Editor)

    def creators(self):
        return self.authors + self.creators
```

But the disadvantage is that you cannot perform the sorting at the database-level but at the Python level:

```
sorted(Publication.objects.all(), key=lambda k: " ".join(p.name for p in k))
```

Comment: The result sets are huge, so this ordering has to happen at the DB level. I've added this as a note to my question. :)

Comment: Why not add an additional column with the sorted list of names while saving? You will have to anyway sort the names while performing the join.

Comment: M2M fields remember? The list of M2M relations can change without the save() ever being called.

Comment: True. But you can still use a `through` model and signals [mentioned in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958540/django-manytomany-signals)

Answer (score 0):

Can I just throw this out there?

You may want `Authors` and `Editors` to inherit from `Contributors`. Since both models will have stuff like first and last names, address, etc.

Comment: This is a severely simplified example. That inheritance would not change the problem, and would only add unnecessary extra lines to the example.

Comment: (that being said, actually merging the two fields into one would be a solution, but is in this case not suitable due to other constraints. :)

Comment: Hmm. You could do it with raw sql, then. But that's a last resort, isn't it.

Comment: Well, using .extra() with `select` is what I'm looking at now to concatenate the two lists of joined M2M values. Tips appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

To sort by whichever field has a value defined, you'll need to create a combined field somewhere the QuerySet can access, either at the model level, using an custom Aggregate, or using an extra clause.

If you don't need to be totally DB agnostic extra is probably the easiest to implement:

```
qs = Publication.objects.extra({
   select={'contributor': "COALESCE(author.name,editor.name)"}
})
qs.extra(order_by = ['contributor'])
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra

If you do need to be DB independent, you should look at using one of the implementations of concat as an aggregate. For example,

http://harkablog.com/inside-the-django-orm-aggregates.html

Comment: I would love to be able to use something like your `extra()` suggestion, but I've not been able to make it work with my M2M fields. Remember that there can be multiple authors associated with every publication, same for the editors. Any ideas?