# How to use RelatedManager add() method in save()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-related-manager

Banging head against the wall again.
I'm trying to add tags using other known fields

```
# models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    field_m2m = models.ManyToManyField('M2mModel', blank=True)
    field_fk = models.ForeignKey('FkModel', blank=True, null=True)
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for inst in self.field_m2m.all():
            self.tags.add(Tag.objects.get(name=inst.name))
        self.tags.add(Tag.objects.get(name=self.field_fk.name))
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class FkModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    ...

class M2mModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    ...
```

I am 100% sure my field_m2m and field_fk aren't empty and what's not less important: there are instances corresponding to EXISTING tags. I have other functions covering this part well. I have also tried hardcoding the strings (`Tag.objects.get(name="mystring")`) to be 101% sure.

Yet, no tags are assigned through admin panel.
I tried to go through the steps in shell and it works there.

```
>>> m = MyModel.objects.get(name='something')
>>> t = Tag.objects.get(name='sometag')
>>> m.tags.add(t)
>>> m.tags.all()
[<Tag: sometag>]
```

How to make it work from save() method?

Also until the the model instance is created for the first time, traceback is complaining about: `"<MyModel: Something>" needs to have a value for field "mymodel" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

I guess I should save the model instance before even doing aforementioned assignments, right? How can I do it all at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to this hint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6200451/1344854
Model save() method stays default. First I tied a tag to my FkModel and M2mModel instances. The rest of the job is done in ModelAdmin.

```
# models.py
class FkModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, blank=True, null=True, related_name='fk')
    ...

class M2mModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, blank=True, null=True, related_name='m2m')
    ...

# admin.py
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        form.save() # as I learned, without saving at this point, obj.field_m2m.all() will be empty
        tags = []
        if obj.field_m2m.all():
            tags += [m2m.tag for m2m in obj.field_m2m.all()]
        if obj.field_fk:
            tags += [obj.field_fk.tag]
        form.cleaned_data['tags'] = tags
        super(MyModelAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that your `MyModel` instance must be saved into database before saving any relationships. It makes sense because for the relationships, the MyModel's id is needed. So you can change the order of the `save` method like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # notice that super class save go first.
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    # also this cicle doesn't make sense since self is a newly
    # created instance so it won't have anythin in field_m2m.all()
    for inst in self.field_m2m.all():
        self.tags.add(Tag.objects.get(name=inst.name))
    # this should work ok if get returns any tag.
    self.tags.add(Tag.objects.get(name=self.field_fk.name))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it helps with the second issue. I still cannot assign tags.

Comment: Sorry but your question is quite big, what's the first issue? I can't find it, can you edit and be more specific?

Comment: In the snipped you provided, that part below super doesn't bring any results. self.tags.add doesn't add anything

Comment: Ok MyModel instance is getting saved to the database but still without any tags. Are you positive sure that There are tags in your database? Also you cicle throug self.field_m2m.all() but loop is invalid because the instance is new so there will be no tags objects associated to MyModel instance yet.

Comment: 100% sure there are tags with exactly the same 'name' (otherwise exception is thrown - I tried hardcoding something fake). self.field_m2m isn't empty, I add some items before hitting save. Same with field_fk.

Comment: Try to add this line again at the end of the method, to save the object twice and see if like that it works: `super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31285/discussion-between-remy-g-and-paulo-bu)