# How to save many to many field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to count tags . I have Post model and tags model and post model has manytomany field to tags. When I want to add new post meanwhile I add tags for post , it has to increase tag count number.

My Post and Tags model:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,blank=True,null=True,verbose_name=_('tags'))

    def save(self)
       super(Post, self).save()
       for i in self.tags.all():
       i.save() 

class Tag(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=30,verbose_name=_('name'))
    count = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True,null=True)

    def save(self):
       self.slug = slugify(self.name.upper())
       self.count = Post.objects.filter(tags__name=self.name).count()
       super(Tag, self).save()
```

When I added new post , I look up the tag model and see count number does not change but when I press the save button in Tags Admin then I see the real count. But I want to see real count when I look up the tag admin without pressing the save button in tag.

Also I want that when I edit the post it should not increase the tags count again.

Comment: You seem to be dealing with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925383/issue-with-manytomany-relationships-not-updating-inmediatly-after-save) issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [m2m_changed signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,blank=True,null=True,verbose_name=_('tags'))

    def save(self)
        super(Post, self).save()
        for tag in self.tags :
            tag.count = tag.post_set.count()
            tag.save()
```

OR, instead of saving the count value into a field, just do the lookup when needed:

```
tag.post_set.count()
```

you could add a function to `Tag` to get this on the easy:

```
def count(self) :
    return self.post_set.count()
```

Comment: post your admin forms and screencaps so i can see what you are talking about. Also, which solution did you go with?

Comment: actualy I dont do anything special in tag admin or post admin. What can i do ?