# CreateView creating two model objects

Tags: python, django, django-views, create-view

I have created a `Form`, where the User sets an `Alarm` object. The `Alarm` object saves as expected to the database. However, the issue is that: another object, which contains only the information completed in the `Form`, also saves to the database.

As I understand, `form_valid()` for `CreateView` saves the form. I have tried the two solutions suggested in [another query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998300/django-createview-how-to-perform-action-upon-save) with no success. I suspect that the issue is caused by either `return super().form_valid(form)` or by `Alarm.objects.create()` in `create_alarm_object()`.

**Views.py**

```
class AlarmCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    """ CreateView for User to create the Alarm object """
    model = Alarm
    form_class = SetAlarmForm
    template_name = 'weather_alarm/set_alarm.html'
    login_url = "/login/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.create_alarm_object(request, form)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        return reverse("weather_alarm:active-alarm", kwargs={'pk':self.object.pk})

    def create_alarm_object(self, request, form):
        """ Function to get User's location from IP and create Alarm object """
        ...
        alarm_object = Alarm.objects.create(
            alarm_id=uuid.uuid4(),
            user=self.request.user,
            timezone=user_timezone,
            city=location.raw['address']['city'],
            country=location.raw['address']['country'],
            time=form.cleaned_data['time'].astimezone(pytz.timezone(user_timezone)),
            temp_conditional=form.cleaned_data['temp_conditional'],
            surf_conditional=form.cleaned_data['surf_conditional'],
            temp_max=form.cleaned_data['temp_max'],
            temp_min=form.cleaned_data['temp_min'],
            surf_max=form.cleaned_data['surf_max'],
            surf_min=form.cleaned_data['surf_min'],
        )
        alarm_object.save()
```

Comment: You can avoid passing the `request` argument, though to `create_alarm_object` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've debugged it right. `super` call to `form_valid` and method `create_alarm_object` are creating two objects.

As you can see in [form_valid method implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L123), it saves the form and returns a `HttpResponseRedirect` object using `success_url`.

Either, do not override `form_valid` method or, use the following code.

**Solution**:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.create_alarm_object(self.request, form)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

**EDIT**:

Update `create_alarm_object` method to set `self.object` and remove redundant `save` call.

```
def create_alarm_object(self, request, form):
    self.object = Alarm.objects.create(...)
    # no `save` call needed, `create` already creates and returns the saved object.
```

Comment: I tried the later solution suggested and received the following error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pk'`. Note, `Primary_Key=True` for `alarm_id`. Do I need to refer to `alarm_id` in `get_success_url()`? However, I checked the database and the Alarm object is now correctly saving one object!

Comment: Apologies. `return reverse("weather_alarm:active-alarm", kwargs={'pk':self.object.pk})`

Comment: That is a different problem. Though you can solve it easily by setting `self.object` in `create_alarm_object` method to the one you created.