# ValueError: needs to have a value for field "cart" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: django, django-signals

I'm facing the problem with the following code:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(CC, blank=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


@receiver(pre_save, sender=Cart)
def cart_update_total(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    total = Decimal(0.00)
    for item in instance.items.all():
        total += item.price
    instance.total = total


@receiver(user_activated)
def user_created(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    cart, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
```

So basically I create a `Cart` model for user who activates account. But also I'm using `pre_save` signal for `Cart` where I calculate total price for products in cart. Therefore `pre_save` function tries to access fields of object which has not been saved yet. Can you guys advise me how can I modify this logic to get it work correctly?

Comment: why not to use post_save signal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django accessing ManyToMany fields from post\_save signal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795811/django-accessing-manytomany-fields-from-post-save-signal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `pre_save` or `post_save` is able to do that because the m2m fields won't be accessible before the actual `Cart` object exists.

You could access the `items` field when people add/remove items from the existing cart, by using [`m2m_changed` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed). So every time user updates the cart, this method gets triggered and update the total.

I don't think it makes much sense to calculate total when cart is created, because, well, if you don't have a cart, how can you add items to it? I would separate these two processes to let user creates a cart first then do the shopping, but it's up to your business logic to make the decision.

Comment: Thanks `m2m_changed` signal is exactly what I need.