# Django: Getting m2m related objects in signals

Tags: python, django

I was kind of trying to see similar questions ([Django accessing ManyToMany fields from post_save signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795811/django-accessing-manytomany-fields-from-post-save-signal)), but still don't see how to get the updated related objects list.

E.g. I have following models

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField

class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField('User')
```

Now I am adding a user to a given blog, via django admin.

So I expect that the signal below, will print all new users (which I have just added)... but... I am getting the old list all the time :(

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Blog.users.through)
def blog_users_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     print instance.users.all()
```

The last line gives old list of users `instance.users.all()`. E.g. users added here are not reflected.

Comment: Is that the original code? I mean, your `sender` is `Blog.users.through` while your m2m is `Blog.user` not `Blog.users`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`m2m_changed` signals are fired at several stages in the save/update process, and there is an `action` argument supplied to the signal handler that tells you what stage it is in. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#m2m-changed):

> **action**
>
> A string indicating the type of update that is done on the relation. This can be one of the following:
>
> **"pre_add"**
>       Sent before one or more objects are added to the relation.
>
> **"post_add"**
>       Sent after one or more objects are added to the relation.
>
> **"pre_remove"**
>       Sent before one or more objects are removed from the relation.
>
> **"post_remove"**
>       Sent after one or more objects are removed from the relation.
>
> **"pre_clear"**
>       Sent before the relation is cleared.
>
> **"post_clear"**
>       Sent after the relation is cleared.

If you catch the `pre_remove` action then you will get all the objects *before* some have been removed from the relationship. That is why you are seeing an apparently unchanged list of users.

Your code needs to check the `action` before deciding what to do. For example:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Blog.users.through)
def blog_users_change(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
    if action == 'pre_remove':
         # This will give you the users BEFORE any removals have happened
         print instance.users.all()
    elif action == 'post_remove':
         # This will give you the users AFTER any removals have happened
         print instance.users.all()
```

Comment: I still think that post_add does not allow me to see the updated list (e.g. with new users I am adding)

Comment: the only case when you dont get the `pk_set` with `UUID`s are `pre_` and `post_clear` signals.