# M2M relations not deleted after clear()

Tags: django

If a user is de-activated I want all memberships deleted. I thought this code in models.py would do it. But is doesn't, the relation is still there.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    membership_type = ManyToManyField(MembershipType, blank=True)

....

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(User, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.old_is_active = self.is_active


def save(self, **kwargs):
    # Membership is cancelled
    if self.old_is_active is True and self.is_active is False:
        self.membership_type.clear()            
    super(User, self).save()
```

I also changed it and debugged it like this.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def clear_membership(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.old_is_active is True and instance.is_active is False:
        print('clearing post_save')
        print(instance.membership_type.all())
        instance.membership_type.clear()
        print(instance.membership_type.all())
```

It prints out the relation.
And after the `clear()` the relations are gone.
But when I look in my Admin GUI, the relation is still there ...?

Comment: Can you try making sure that the `.clear()` line is executed via debugger or a `print` statement? If it is, try opening a shell and running `whichever_user.membership_type.clear()` and seeing if that clears the relationship.

Comment: I checked with a ```print``` statement and it gets executed.
I checked in the shell, and it clears the relationship.

Could it be, that it is before the ```save()```

Comment: That seems possible.

Comment: I added a new version to the original question. Do you have any more ideas how to tackle this?

Comment: Are you adding an instance somewhere else automatically? You can check the ids on the items being deleted in the database and compare it with those after they exist again.

Comment: I now used the ```on_transaction_commit``` function describe here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795811/django-accessing-manytomany-fields-from-post-save-signal

And that works!