# Django: Auto populate m2m field of a model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a category kind of model (called Tag):

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    #...
```

Used as m2m field in another model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(...)
    type = models.CharField(...)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
```

Now, suppose an order is created and program wants to assign some tags to it automatically. Say, program wants to add `Order.type` to its`Order.tag` list. (Suppose `Order.type` happens to be same as a valid `Tag.name`)
I tried Order's `post_save` to no luck:

```
def order_post_save_reciever(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    #..., disconnect, ...
    instance.tag.add(Tag.objects.filter(name=instance.type))
    instance.save()
    #.... reconnec, t.....
```

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23796604/805896), I have to use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed), but I don't know how. Do you know how to add a tag here?
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have to use signals? Are not both models in your own project? Also, the answer you linked you Apparently haven't read, because it explicitly states not to use `post_save`.

Comment: @Melvyn maybe I haven't explained it correctly. Yes, I read the link and realized `post_save` is NOT the correct place. Moreover, I don't know if/how I should use the signal. That is why I asked :) . I guess it is you who didn't read the question correctly. What is your solution? (if you know any). That is what we are seeking after all.

Comment: My solution is not to use signals, if both my are my models. If you save an Order, you can add a tag in its save method. Why use signals? In fact, if Order is my model, I don't care who's model Tag is, I don't have to use signals.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **instance.save()** as it'll create a loop.

Comment: To show less unrelated code, the disconnect and reconnect lines are not shown here.