# Django many-to-many add having inconsistent effect in functions, works on console

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm creating a lesson planning tool. Each lesson covers multiple syllabus points, and has associated resources. When you save a lesson, I want to make sure that the syllabus points for the lesson are also saved to the resources.

I've tried using both `signals` and overriding the save method to make this work, but keep getting weird results.

**models.py**

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    lessonslot = models.ForeignKey(TimetabledLesson, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    classgroup = models.ForeignKey(ClassGroup, null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    syllabus_points_covered = models.ManyToManyField(SyllabusPoint, blank=True)
    lesson_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    requirements = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    sequence = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    syllabus = models.ForeignKey(Syllabus, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ( ("lessonslot", "date"),
                           ("classgroup", "sequence"))

class LessonResources(models.Model):
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    resource_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=RESOURCE_TYPES, null=False, blank=False)
    resource_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=False)
    link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    students_can_view_before = models.BooleanField()
    students_can_view_after = models.BooleanField()
    available_to_all_classgroups = models.BooleanField()
    syllabus_points = models.ManyToManyField(SyllabusPoint, blank=True)

    def set_syllabus_points(self):
        if self.lesson:
            points = self.lesson.syllabus_points_covered.all().order_by('pk')
            for point in points:
                self.syllabus_points.add(point)
            print ('In set_syllabus_points')
            print(self.syllabus_points.all())
        return self
```

**signals.py**

```
from timetable.models import LessonResources, Lesson
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, m2m_changed
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Lesson.syllabus_points_covered.through)
def post_update_lesson_syllabus_pts(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """ After adding a syllabus point to a lesson, update its resources"""
    resources = instance.resources()
    for resource in resources:
        resource.set_syllabus_points()


@receiver(post_save, sender=LessonResources)
def update_resources(sender, instance, **kwargs):
""" After adding a resource, check its syllabus points match its lesson """
    print('Before set_syllabus_points')
    print(instance.pk)
    print(instance.syllabus_points.all())
    instance.set_syllabus_points()
    print('After set_syllabus_points')
    print(instance.syllabus_points.all())
```

**Console Output**

```
Before set_syllabus_points
105
<QuerySet []>
After set_syllabus_points
<QuerySet [<SyllabusPoint: Motion and Measurement 1.1.1 Use and describe the use of rules and measuring cylinders to find a length or a volume>, <SyllabusPoint: Motion and Measurement 1.1.3 Obtain an average value for a small distance and for a short interval of time by measuring multiples (including the period of a pendulum)>, <SyllabusPoint: Motion and Measurement 1.1.3 Understand that a micrometer screw gauge is used to measure very small distances>, <SyllabusPoint: Motion and Measurement 1.2.1 Define speed>, <SyllabusPoint: Motion and Measurement 1.2.2 Calculate Average speed from total distance / total time>, <SyllabusPoint: Forces 1.3.1 Explain that In the absence of an unbalanced force, an object will either remain at rest or travel with a constant speed in a straight line. Unbalanced forces change motion.>]>
```

The first one (`post_update_lesson_syllabus_pts`) works fine, but adding the points to a resource after that resource has been created does not work.

In the debugger, I can see that `resource.set_syllabus_points()` is being called after a new resource is created or modified. I can also see that `self.syllabus_points.add(point)` is passing a valid syllabuspoint as `point`. However, when I then check the resource (e.g. `print(resources.syllabus_points.all())` after eveyrthing has completed, I get an empty queryset! I'm creating the resource in the admin interface (using an inline formset attached to the lesson), and none of the syllabus points are selected.

When the function runs, the print statement in `set_syllabus_points` outputs the correct queryset - why aren't they getting to the database?

Thanks in advance for all your help, I'm sure it's something silly I've missed.

**UPDATE 1**

Okay, so I think I've narrowed it down to something that's happening in the admin interface.

I've added some `print` statements shown above to see what's going on.

Here's the output from running an interractive shell:

```
>>>> resource = LessonResources.objects.get(pk=115)
>>>> resource.syllabus_points.all()
<QuerySet []>
>>>> resource.set_syllabus_points()
In set_syllabus_points
<QuerySet [<SyllabusPoint: Motion and Measurement 1.1.1 Use and describe the use of rules and measuring cylinders to find a length or a volume>, <SyllabusPoint: Motion and Measurement 1.1.3 Obtain an average value for a small distance and for a short interval of time by measuring multiples (including the period of a pendulum)>, <SyllabusPoint: Motion and Measurement 1.1.3 Understand that a micrometer screw gauge is used to measure very small distances>, <SyllabusPoint: Motion and Measurement 1.2.1 Define speed>, <SyllabusPoint: Motion and Measurement 1.2.2 Calculate Average speed from total distance / total time>, <SyllabusPoint: Forces 1.3.1 Explain that In the absence of an unbalanced force, an object will either remain at rest or travel with a constant speed in a straight line. Unbalanced forces change motion.>]>
>>>> resource.syllabus_points.all()
<QuerySet [<SyllabusPoint: Motion and Measurement 1.1.1 Use and describe the use of rules and measuring cylinders to find a length or a volume>, <SyllabusPoint: Motion and Measurement 1.1.3 Obtain an average value for a small distance and for a short interval of time by measuring multiples (including the period of a pendulum)>, <SyllabusPoint: Motion and Measurement 1.1.3 Understand that a micrometer screw gauge is used to measure very small distances>, <SyllabusPoint: Motion and Measurement 1.2.1 Define speed>, <SyllabusPoint: Motion and Measurement 1.2.2 Calculate Average speed from total distance / total time>, <SyllabusPoint: Forces 1.3.1 Explain that In the absence of an unbalanced force, an object will either remain at rest or travel with a constant speed in a straight line. Unbalanced forces change motion.>]>
```

We also seem to be seeing the correct output when `set_syllabus_points()` is called by `signals` due to creating or updating a resource.

However, even though our console log is showing it's added the points, they seems to re-set back to an empty queryset again at some points as the admin interface is loaded. Could this be caused by something in the admin views / forms caching the many-to-many relations and re-setting then back to their initial values?

**UPDATE 2**

As suspected, it's definitely a modelAdmin thing. [This StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925383/issue-with-manytomany-relationships-not-updating-immediately-after-save/1925784#1925784) and [this blog post](https://timonweb.com/posts/many-to-many-field-save-method-and-the-django-admin/) explain what's happening - now I just have to work out how to override the default behaviour for a tabularInLine form...

Comment: You're calling `print(resource.syllabus_points)` right? You wrote `print(resource.syllabus_point)`  (without the `s`) but I don't know if that was a typo.

Comment: @Cole: You're absolutely right, careless typo! I'll update the question.

Comment: I was talking about at the end of `syllabus_point` -> `syllabus_points`, is that not a typo?

Comment: Can you try to put a print statement in your signal after the completion of for loop to syllabus_points on resources?

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar I've added some print statements as you requested. This is getting weirder - they're showing the correct points added! But once I  return to the admin interface, the points are missing again. Any ideas how to track down where the change is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in **Update 2**, this issue was caused by the way that the Django admin interface handles many-to-many relations.

The django admin interface was using a `TabularInline` admin form so that I could edit lessons and their associated resources at one;

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from timetable.models import *
from timetable.forms import LessonForm
# Register your models here.


class ResourcesInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = LessonResources

class LessonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = LessonForm
    inlines = [
        ResourcesInLine,
    ]


admin.site.register(LessonSlot)
admin.site.register(TimetabledLesson)
admin.site.register(Lesson, LessonAdmin)
admin.site.register(LessonResources)
admin.site.register(LessonSuspension)
```

When I saved the admin form, the basic order of what was happening was:

1. The lesson details were saved.
2. Resources were saved, ignoring the m2m relations.
3. Saving the resource triggered the `post-save` signal for `set_syllabus_points()`
4. Syllabus points were added to the resource.
5. The admin module cleared all the m2m relations, as noted in the Django documentation.
6. The admin module added each of the syllabus points as shown in the admin interface.

It was step 5 that was the problem. When I saved the `lesson` form, the `syllabus_points` for the lesson resources were all blank. The signal worked as expected and added them, but the admin module then cleared them again because its expected behaviour was to make the `LessonResoure` instance fit what was on the initial form - which was nothing!

My long-term solution to this will be to build a custom form outside the admin interface to do this myself. Since this won't call the `clean` method on the many-to-many relation, this problem will stop.

In the meantime, I've removed `syllabus_points` from the admin interface for creating a new lesson. This means that the `clear` method doesn't get called, and fixed the issue.

**Fix**
Edit the admin interface to remove the many-to-many relation, e.g;

```
from django.contrib import admin
from timetable.models import *
from timetable.forms import LessonForm
# Register your models here.


class ResourcesInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = LessonResources
    exclude = ('syllabus_points',)

class LessonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = LessonForm
    inlines = [
        ResourcesInLine,
    ]


admin.site.register(LessonSlot)
admin.site.register(TimetabledLesson)
admin.site.register(Lesson, LessonAdmin)
admin.site.register(LessonResources)
admin.site.register(LessonSuspension)
```

Huge thanks to @Cole and @Rajesh for pointing me in the right directions!

Answer (score 0):

In your `post_update_lesson_syllabus_pts` add statement `resource.save()` once your have called `set_syllabus_points()`. Post that you should be able to see the syllabus points for your resource.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply! I've tried saving after adding, but it doesn't seem to have any effect; the debugger still shows `save` being called (although I had to do some re-jigging to prevent an infinite loop), but it doesn't end up saved to the model. Also, shouldn't many-to-many relations be saved to the database as soon as `.add` is called?

Comment: @JamesWright Yes, `.add` will save the many-to-many relation to the through table on call –– the way you used it is correct.

Comment: Yes @JamesWright they do I was incorrect on that part.

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean by "I got nothing returned" is that you got an object that looked something like this:

```
<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x1111eb518>
```

Then that's not what you think it is. When you execute `resource.syllabus_points`, what you're doing is accessing that `LessonResources` instance's *related* `SyllabusPoints` objects through a ManyToMany manager. You'd be returned a similar object, with less constraints, if you called `SyllabusPoints.objects`. Much like you would with any other model manager, you need to call something like `all`, `get`, or `filter` on that manager. In this example, all I have at hand is a Blog app where I have a `blog.Post` model with a ManyToManyField to `blog.Tag`. It's all the same though:

```
>>> from naguine.apps import get_model
>>> Post = get_model('blog.Post')
>>> Tag = get_model('blog.Tag')
>>> p = Post.objects.create()
>>> p.tags.add(Tag.objects.create(name='testtag'))
>>> p.tags
<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x1111eb518>
>>> p.tags.all()
<QuerySet [<Tag: testtag>]>
```

Comment: Thanks Cole, I've edited the question to show that I get nothign when I run `syllabus.objects.all()`. When I look in the debugger, what I'm seeing after each run of `self.syllabus_points.add(point)` is `tracker.SyllabusPoints.None`. Interestlingly, I've added a print statement after each add. This outputs the correct queryset showing the added points, so somehow they're not saving to the database.

Comment: @JamesWright Unless I'm mistaken, I believe you're looking at the wrong model for added objects. After adding, try running `SyllabusPoints.objects.all()` where `SyllabusPoints` is the class, not the instance. Let me know what that returns.